# Use dependency injection in static class

Tags: c#, class, dependency-injection, static

I need to use Dependency Injection in a static class.

the method in the static class needs the value of an injected dependency.

The following code sample demonstrates my problem:

```
public static class XHelper
{
    public static TResponse Execute(string metodo, TRequest request)
    {
        // How do I retrieve the IConfiguracion dependency here?
        IConfiguracion x = ...;

        // The dependency gives access to the value I need
        string y = x.apiUrl;

        return xxx;
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to inject IConfiguration ? Why not non-static class?

Comment: Yes, I need inject IConfiguration, if I do not find a solution I will have to use no-static class

Comment: If you could do this, this would be weird and it would likely need to be refactored later. You static class has no right to ask for a dependency, it defeats the point of being static and the main spirit of DI

Comment: You also have the option of using method injection `public static TResponse Execute(string metodo, TRequest request, IConfiguration conf)`

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You basically have two options:

1. Change the class from `static` to an instance class and supply the dependency through [Constructor Injection](https://mng.bz/oN9j).
2. Supply the dependency to the class's public method through [Method Injection](https://mng.bz/jONp).

Here are examples for each option.

#### Option 1. Change the class from static to an instance class

Change the class from `static` to an instance class and supply `IConfiguration` through [Constructor Injection](https://mng.bz/oN9j). `XHelper` should in that case be injected into the constructor of its consumers. Example:

```cs
public class XHelper
{
    private readonly IConfiguration config;
    
    public XHelper(IConfiguration config)
    {
        this.config = config ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("config");
    }

    public TResponse Execute(string metodo, TRequest request)
    {
        string y = this.config.apiUrl;

        return xxx;
    }
}
```

Consequence of this option is that the class `XHelper` must itself become a constructor argument of the constructor its consumers, and thus itself injected. This results in changes to the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) by either adding a registration for `XHelper`—in case a DI Container is used—or to create and inject it to its consumers—in case [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) is practiced.

#### 2. Supply the `IConfiguration` to the `Execute` method through Method Injection.

Example:

```cs
public static class XHelper
{
    public static TResponse Execute(
        string metodo, TRequest request, IConfiguration config)
    {
        if (config is null) throw new ArgumentNullException("config");
    
        string y = config.apiUrl;

        return xxx;
    }
}
```

Consequence of this option is that the consumers of `XHelper` must supply the `IConfiguration` dependency while calling `XHelper.Execute`. This most likely means that `IConfiguration` must be injected into their own constructor.

#### Less favorable options

There are of course more options to consider, but I consider them all to be less favorable, because they would either cause [code smells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) or [anti-patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).

For instance:

- You might be inclined to make the DI Container accessible through a static method and call it from inside your static class, but this is an [anti-pattern called Service Locator](https://mng.bz/WaQw).
- You could allow setting the static class's dependencies through static properties on that class, but this leads to the [Ambient Context anti-pattern](https://mng.bz/4O7v).
- You could change the class to an instance class, but instead of using Constructor Injection make use of Property Injection, but this causes [Temporal Coupling](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/), which is a code smell.

Comment: @Steven When the 1st option is implemented, do we also need to add this class a  service?

Comment: @Steven In a web api environment with your second scenario, where do I get the config from in my controller method?

Comment: You inject it through the controller's constructor.

Comment: You can also create a static property and a public static method in your static class and set the configuration property there instead of passing it in your methods, makes it a little cleaner imo.

Comment: @sridawg what you are describing is called Ambient Context and it's [an anti-pattern](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-ambient-context-anti-pattern/).

Comment: sadly none of this useful in many scenarios.

Comment: @Tommix, if my answer doesn't fit your scenario, you might want to raise a new question here at SO.

Answer (score -2):

i had this problem and i developed this nuget package: [ServiceCollectionAccessorService](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceCollectionAccessorService/)

repo:  [ServiceCollectionAccessorService](https://github.com/exitxhu/ServiceCollectionAccessorService)
it is basically a static class that holds access to root service collection which you can build your provider from it:

```
private static LogData GetLogData() => ServiceCollectionAccessor.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<LogData>();
```

this package is operational in my work and we did not have any problem.
I had no problem resolving scoped services as well.
I hope this could help anyone with the same problem.

Comment: This is a very bad idea. First of all, it is an implementation of the [Service Locator anti-pattern](https://mng.bz/WaQw). However, in your code example you are building the DI Container over and over again. This can cause performance problems, memory leaks, and [Torn Lifestyles](https://simpleinjector.org/diatl). It might have worked in your specific situation, but I would warn anybody from using this approach.

Comment: ty for your advise, i will try to look for a better way