# Is DI to static field not good?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, static, code-injection

I have an issue with component bean that has static field in it.

And I did DI to static field to implement static method so that other class can call this method without DI to itself

Is this unnatural stuff? Just someone has doubt on this so..

**-Edit**

I attached some code that shows what I want

```html
@Component
public class CompWithStatic {

    private static InjectedObj injectedObj ;

    @Autowired
    CompWithStatic(InjectedObj injectedObj ) {
        CompWithStatic.injectedObj = injectedObj;
    }

    public static String doStaticA(String str){
        //do something with injectedObj
        return str + " method A ";
    }

    public static String doStaticB(String str){
        //do something with injectedObj
        return str + " method B ";
    }
}


public enum EnumType {
    ENUMA(str-> CompWithStatic.doStaticA(str)),
    ENUMB(str-> CompWithStatic.doStaticB(str));

    private Function<String,String> expression;

    EnumType(Function expression) {
        this.expression = expression;
    }

    public String doExpress(String str){
        return expression.apply(str);
    }
}
```

what I intended was each Enum case has dynamic method
so you can use it as like this

```html
        EnumType.ENUMA.doExpress("str");
```

Please let me know if it's unnatural way!

Comment: Super unclear text..

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55213803/use-dependency-injection-in-static-class

Comment: sorry I just add this question with my phone.  i will edit this question with codes when I can get to computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static fields are okay to some extend, typically constants within bean are defined as static final constants.

But static methods within bean are not at all recommended as this there is no participation of static methods in object which will not have any place in DI. (Although it shouldn't be an issue to have static methods within bean as these references will be replaced by Class during compilation time it self).