# Get AspNetCore.SinalR HubInstance (IHubContext) in Singleton

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, singleton

I want to get a SignalR IHubContext in my Singleton Class, which is outside of the hub.

I create the singleton like this:

```
private static GameManager instance;
public static GameManager Instance
{
    get
    {
        lock (padLock)
        {
            return instance ?? (instance = new GameManager());
        }
    }
}
```

Which means the Constructor with the IHubContext parameter doesn't work.
From MS Docs:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHubContext<NotificationHub> _hubContext;

    public HomeController(IHubContext<NotificationHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }
}
```

Is there a workaround so I still have the GameManager as a Singleton and access to my SignalR Hub to send timed updates?

I'm sorry if I missed something, I'm completely new to ASP.net and signalR

Comment: I believe this boils down to a more general question of "how do I inject dependencies into into a static class?". In which case the solution will be more or less the same as what's been provided in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55213803/use-dependency-injection-in-static-class

Comment: While this would probably be the technically correct way, I'm searching for a solution to keep the singleton pattern with the GameManager and sending regular messages from there

Answer (score -1):

I found a (apparently hacky) way to circumvent the dependency Injection:

Add a static IHubContext into your Hub:

```
public static IHubContext<GameHub> Current { get; set; }
```

In Startup.cs add the IHubContext to the Hub:

```
GameHub.Current = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IHubContext<GameHub>>();
```

Now you can send messages from anywhere using:

```
GameHub.Current.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveBeat");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just inject the `IHubContext` in any class, you don't need to add it in the hub.

So you delete that Current static IHubContext and go to your class where you want to inject the hub and you add:

```cs
private IHubContext<GameHub> GameHub
{
    get
    {
        return this.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHubContext<GameHub>>();
    }
}
```