# Access DI service from static class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, blazor

There is now an extension method on ElementReference for setting focus to that element from a razor component.  Great.

But ...

I have created a JSInteropService in the DI with methods such as SelectAll:

```
public class JSInteropService : IAsyncDisposable
{
    private readonly Lazy<Task<IJSObjectReference>> moduleTask;

    public JSInteropService(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
    {
        moduleTask = new(() => jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
            "import", "./_content/MyComponentClassLib/mycomponents.js").AsTask());
    }


    public async ValueTask SelectAll(ElementReference elementReference)
    {
        var module = await moduleTask.Value;
        await module.InvokeVoidAsync("selectAll", elementReference);
    }
```

It works fine, but this requires the razor component to have JSInteropService injected and then for every such capability (like SalectAll) I call that service with a reference to ElementReference.  E.g:

```
@inject JSInteropService JS

<input @ref=@EditTextBox />

@code {
    ElementReference EditTextBox;

    async Task SelectAll()
    {
        await JS.SelectAll(EditTextBox)
    }
}
```

But what I'd like to do is add another extension method to ElementReference called SelectAll, with the intention that I can replace my SelectAll() method above and just call:

```
await EditTextBox.SelectAllAsync()
```

But, this would need my static extensions class to be able to get hold of JSInteropService.

Is it possible to extract that from the DI container when I don't have injection available to me in the static class?

My razor component is in a Razor Class Library.

Comment: I realize this might not be what you are really looking for - but what about passing the JSInterop service as an argument to your extension? That would at least allow you to call SelectAll on the element instead of JS making it a bit more "semantically correct"..

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55213803/use-dependency-injection-in-static-class

Comment: Thank you, both!  Yup, passing the required service into each method call would work but feels baaaad.  After all, MS have created an extension method for FocusAsync which stands on its own two feet; I wonder what magic they use?  I guess the fact that they've only provided that method as an extension should be telling us something!

Comment: You don't have to pass the service, you can simply pass the IJSRuntime object. No magic. You can view their code to see how hard they've worked in order to fool you to believe that it is magic. You can imitate them. I wouldn't waste my time just so that my code would look nice.

Comment: Thanks enet.  Fair enough, but I'd still need to inject the IJSRuntime into my razor component and pass that to the extension methods with every call, wouldn't I?  Aren't we just moving the "problem" from the JSInteropService to IJSRuntime.

Comment: enet, that "hard work" you talk about ... Could it be: 
IJSRuntime js = new ServiceCollection().BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IJSRuntime>()?  Can that be used to shoestring access to the IJSRuntime (or JSInteropService) when I don't have injection available to me in a static class?  Although, I'd then need to acquire a "moduleTask" for each and every JS call, instead of it being instantiated once in the constructor of my JSInteropService.  Does what I'm saying make sense?  Must admit, I don't fully understand the "Lazy" declaration of "moduleTask".

Comment: OK.  Just read up on "Lazy".  So, could the moduleTask be stored in a static variable in the extensions class so its only created once and only imports the JS file once.  To me, this means that I could wrap all of this up in a static class with a combination of storing moduleTask in a static var and using the ServiceCollection().BuildServiceProvider()GetRequiredServce<IJSRuntime>() approach.  It's late here!  I may be thinking crazy!

Comment: Just tested.  No good.  So that new ServiceCollection() ...  approach doesn't work.  Tells me that no IJSRuntime has been registered (even though it get injected into JSInteropService).  Is this because I'm using a NEW ServiceCollection as opposed to the ServiceCollection created at Startup?  I can just leave it where I am and pass in the ElementReference as I have been doing.  No biggie.  Am just intrigued now.

Comment: You can see how they get an IJSRuntime out of "thin air" [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Components/Web/src/ElementReferenceExtensions.cs#L44). Essentially, the ElementReference has a reference to an object holding a reference to it, you just have to cast it.
It's internal for a reason, though. They know it's not a nice solution, so they can change it in the future without other things breaking.

Answer (score 0):

I feel this question is more about code organization than Blazor or JS interop.
You "want" to have an extension method, and that is great for simple scenarios. But when you add that you might have to provide additional dependencies to your calls, you'll see it's not always immediately obvious to just tack on a few other parameters. This is a form of dependency injection called `method injection`: your method takes its dependencies as simple parameters. This is not too object-oriented in most cases, which might make it feel "weird", as you have said.

I propose 4 possible solutions, from "clean" to "messy", in order:

1. The "cleanest" solution is for you to provide the `IJSRuntime` as a parameter to the extension method. This is "clean" as you are not depending on some other objects' states or behavior to get the instance. So you inject `IJSRuntime` wherever you wish to use the extension method. This is a good way to start, because the dependency graph will be clean.
2. Another solution might be to use a different base class (something other than the basic `ComponentBase`) for your components that you want to "enhance" with custom functionality, which already contain the logic you wrote. This will be syntactically different, because you won't be able to define extension methods in non-static classes, but you'll be able to centralize your injected `IJSRuntime`, because Blazor supports defining injectables via the `[Inject]` attribute in base classes. Then, also in your custom `ComponentBase`, you can provide the implementation as well.

```cs
public abstract class MyComponentBase : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject]
    public IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; } = null!;

    public async ValueTask SelectAllAsync(ElementReference elementReference)
    {
        var module = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "[{path-to-js}.js]");
        await module.InvokeVoidAsync("selectAll", elementReference);
    }
}
```

3. A third option would be to get the `IJSRuntime` reference from the `ElementReference` itself. This is not documented, but you can do it the same way the "magic" `FocusAsync` does as you can see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Components/Web/src/ElementReferenceExtensions.cs#L44). This approach is internal for a reason - it's not nice and implies there is a hidden dependency which they don't want you, as the dev, to rely on (that is, `ElementReference` already indirectly relies on `IJSRuntime`, which, frankly, seems messy).
4. A possible fourth option is to store the `IJSRuntime` reference somewhere you can get ahold of it. This is not too nice either. If you're using Blazor WASM, it can be a static variable somewhere you can access it easily (maybe in you static extension method class itself), but if you're using Blazor Server, a static variable is not a good idea, as there services are inherently "Scoped" in lifecycle to the current user session. Thus, you're left with dependency injecting whatever you like, essentially leaving you with the solutions outlined above.

---

One more thing. With the new JS interop in .NET 7 it seems they will be moving away from the current `IJSRuntime` implementations. The new `[JSImport]`/`[JSExport]` APIs are for generating marshalling code from WASM to JavaScript (it doesn't work with Blazor Server at the moment), and is much faster, but doesn't use `ElementReference` or JSON serialization at all. In my experience, it's harder to use but might be worth for you [to look into it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/import-export-interop?view=aspnetcore-7.0), if you're app is WASM only. It also handles JavaScript modules out-of-the-box, and you can cheaply import the modules you need as you need them.