# Why do I get this error in the static class ? -> Readonly field _logger is never assigned

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, microsoft-extensions-logging

I am using ILogger in my static class.

The codes in the class shown in below:

```
internal static class LicenceSetter
{
    private static ILogger _logger;

    internal static void WorkWithStream(Action<Stream> setLicence, string name = null)
    {
        try
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var declaringType = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType;
            Debug.Assert(declaringType != null, "declaringType != null");

            name = name ?? $"{declaringType.Namespace}.{AsposeTotalLic2017FileName}";

            using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(name))
            {
                setLicence(stream);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _logger.LogError(exception,"Error loading embedded resource for aspose licence");
            Trace.TraceError("Error loading embedded resource for aspose licence");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

But I get this error while building the application: `Readonly field _logger is never assigned`

Comment: Well _logger is never assigned a value, i.e. its always null. Your _logger.LogError would throw a null reference exception.

Comment: I searched for how to assign a value to ILogger but I have not found the solution. @AlexK.

Comment: Are you using a flavour of ASP.Net that uses dependency injection? If so you can register the class a singleton and inject an ILogger instance in to the class constructor.

Comment: @AlexK. I have tried to have a constructor in the class but it says you cannot have a constructor in a static class with argument !

Comment: hi masoud, i'm playing dumb. for one, its a `readonly` which meant it never be assigned apart from constructor. even worse, you put the class as `static` which meant you can only rely on [static constructor/initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) of which **DI implementation won't even touch**. so.. rethink your strategy here.

Comment: @BagusTesa I have removed readonly you were corroct. this is a old version class so I cannot change the strategy, I need to inject ILogger to the class. is there any way ?

Comment: @Masoud its all depend to whatever dependency injection you were using - what alex asked. but i prefer if you really rethink your strategy and not mixing up old school doctrine with new shiny ones.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where your logger is being assigned in that class.
You may be getting a null reference exception by accessing the object.

Answer (score 0):

You have not set it to anything. Consider using dependency injection and inject it through the constructor

Comment: But it's a static class. I cannot have a constructor

Comment: Can you refactor so you can pass logger into the method

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the `_logger` object to the implementation either from the constructor and/or by using some Dependency Injection (DI) Container.

Comment: I have tried, but it says in static classes you cannot have a constructor with argument !

Answer (score 0):

As allready mentioned the variable is not assigned in that class.

To handle injection within your static class, check this post out, on how to deal with that. (e.g. with method injection)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55244379

Answer (score 0):

ILogger property should not be static.

I found a solution for that:

```
internal static class LicenceSetter
{

//Removed - private static ILogger _logger;

internal static void WorkWithStream(ILogger logger,Action<Stream> setLicence, string name = null)
{
    try
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var declaringType = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType;
        Debug.Assert(declaringType != null, "declaringType != null");

        name = name ?? $"{declaringType.Namespace}.{AsposeTotalLic2017FileName}";

        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(name))
        {
            setLicence(stream);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        logger.LogError(exception,"Error loading embedded resource for aspose licence");
        Trace.TraceError("Error loading embedded resource for aspose licence");
        throw;
    }
}
```

}